# Support for the Page Object pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd, pageobjects

In Ruby-land we have Capybara and Webrat to drive our web browsers during functional testing with Cucumber.

What I can't find is something like Geb in Groovy/Java-land which seems like it works on one level of abstraction higher than Capybara. This is the description of Geb from [the Geb website](http://www.gebish.org/).

> Geb is a browser automation solution.
>
> It brings together the power of WebDriver, the elegance of jQuery
>   content selection, the robustness of Page Object modelling and the
>   expressiveness of the Groovy language.

Capybara already brings together WebDriver (usually Selenium) and jQuery-style content selection. But it doesn't have any support for the [Page Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) idea. (You create classes to represent the pages under test, so the steps carry out actions upon them rather than look at the DOM directly all the time. Like a mini-API for your page.)

To give an example of the kind of useful feature I'm looking for, I understand from a colleague that Geb can automatically assert that the page under test matches the attributes in the virtual page object which represents the page to your Cucumber tests.

Comment: Google for "Ruby Page Object" gives this: https://github.com/cheezy/page-object . . . if this is not suitable, consider asking on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead, because asking for links or to external resources is considered off-topic on the main Stack Overflow site.

Comment: This will likely be closed as off-topic, but try this: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/site_prism/frames

Comment: Probably shouldnt tag this with [geb] as it's not really related.

Comment: Thanks all, I've removed the [geb] tag. I thought people who have experience with Geb might know of alternatives in other languages as they might miss the framework when they code in {not Java}. Not seen softwarerecs but it sounds like that would be the place. If nobody provides another answer I'll eventually answer it when I figure out the page-object gem, but happy for it to be closed if mods think it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made use of [Site Prism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) for page-objects in a fairly large application.  Cheezy's [page-object gem](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) was the other gem that I considered at the time but it didn't make use of Capybara (which when used correctly can aid with timing issues).  The page-object gem has it's own "wait" mechanism.

There's also [another gem](https://github.com/andyw8/capybara-page-object) but I suspect it's abandoned.

The **page-object gem** will give you test code along these lines:

```rb
class LoginPage
  include PageObject

  page_url "http://example.com/login"
  text_field(:username, :id => 'username')
  text_field(:password, :id => 'password')
  button(:login, :id => 'login')

  def login_with(username, password)
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    login
  end
end

# in your tests
visit_page LoginPage do |page|
page.login_with('testuser1@example.com', 'incorrect')
page.wait_until do # using default of 30s for this asynch call
  page.text.include? 'invalid user or password'
end
expect(page).to have_content 'invalid user or password'
```

More examples can be seen in this project: https://github.com/JonKernPA/pageobject  and on the wiki https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Elements

**Site Prism** looks like this:

```ruby
class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page
  set_url '/login'

  element :username_field, '#username'
  element :password_field, '#password'
  element :login_button, '#login'

  def login_with(username, password)
    username_field.set username
    password_field.set password
    login_button.click # this uses capybara to find('#login').click
  end
end

# in your tests
@page = LoginPage.new
@page.load
@page.login_with('testuser1@example.com', 'incorrect')
# capybara automatically waits for us
expect(@page).to have_content 'invalid user or password'
```

The Site Prism README has a lot of good examples.  Everything else you need to know is in [Capybara's](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) excellent README and documentation.

There are of course far more differences than these small example shows.
I would advise you to take a look at both and decide what your requirements are.